# Condition-based forwardfill for pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Trying to do a forwardfill using pyspark. I wonder why filled and filled1 gets the same. What I want to is apply forwardfill only when the flag column equals 1.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, expr, when, last
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

data = [("person1", "1", 100, 0),
        ("person1", "2", 1000, 1),
        ("person1", "3", 1000, 0),
        ("person2", "1", 5, 0),
        ("person2", "2", 5, 0),
        ("person2", "3", 3, 0),
        ("person2", "4", 10, 1),
        ("person2", "5", 10, 0)]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["person", "date", "salary", "flag"])

window = Window.partitionBy("person").orderBy("date").rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)
filled_df = df.withColumn("filled", when(col("flag") == 1, last(col("salary"), True).over(window)).otherwise(col("salary")))
filled_df = filled_df.withColumn("filled1",  last(col("salary"), True).over(window))

filled_df.show()
```

```
-------+----+------+----+------+-------+
| person|date|salary|flag|filled|filled1|
+-------+----+------+----+------+-------+
|person1|   1|   100|   0|   100|    100|
|person1|   2|  1000|   1|  1000|   1000|
|person1|   3|  1000|   0|  1000|   1000|
|person2|   1|     5|   0|     5|      5|
|person2|   2|     5|   0|     5|      5|
|person2|   3|     3|   0|     3|      3|
|person2|   4|    10|   1|    10|     10|
|person2|   5|    10|   0|    10|     10|
+-------+----+------+----+------+-------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIU, you need to fill with the prev record salary if `flag=1`, then you need to bound the window function to the prev record `-1` and not the `Window.currentRow`, since `Window.currentRow` will always make the `last` function to retrieve the same record value

```py
window = Window.partitionBy("person").orderBy("date").rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, -1)
```

**Another simple option is to use the `lag` function and remove the `rowsBetween`**
Just note that this solution will pick up the prev element even it is null

```py
window = Window.partitionBy("person").orderBy("date")
filled_df = df.withColumn("filled", when(col("flag") == 1, lag(col("salary"), 1).over(window)).otherwise(col("salary")))
filled_df = filled_df.withColumn("filled1",  lag(col("salary"), 1).over(window))
```

```
+-------+----+------+----+------+-------+
| person|date|salary|flag|filled|filled1|
+-------+----+------+----+------+-------+
|person1|   1|   100|   0|   100|   null|
|person1|   2|  1000|   1|   100|    100|
|person1|   3|  1000|   0|  1000|   1000|
|person2|   1|     5|   0|     5|   null|
|person2|   2|     5|   0|     5|      5|
|person2|   3|     3|   0|     3|      5|
|person2|   4|    10|   1|     3|      3|
|person2|   5|    10|   0|    10|     10|
+-------+----+------+----+------+-------+
```

Comment: Thx. It works then, however, the function last dosen't make sense to me when the window function has -1? Why do I need last still?

Comment: @Henri yes in this case it seems unnecessarily complicated, I have added another option using the `lag` function which is much simpler and clearer